# Putting validation at property level in entity of entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, validation, t4

I am using T4 template to generate entity from .edmx file, now i want to put validation on entity,

My requirements are :

1) I am developing win application,Each property of entity is binding with data source, so want to keep strategy, that when save button is pressed ,corresponding entity is validated and  controls which binds invalid property will display error icon,

2) I dont want to keep my validation in data layer, because there are some business validation and custom messages in business layer...

Comment: One more limitation , due to business validation, i can not use validation using data annotations.

Comment: Move your entities to business layer and implement validation in entities.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka , actually i dont want to change any code from auto generate class, and entities are parts of data layer so can not do it... is there any other option?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the Fluent Validation framework. The approach is to implement an external Validator for each entity you want to validate.
It's very easy but the most important thing it allows you to choose in which layer you want to place validation.
You find it on codeplex at:

http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

You can gain the separation between entities and validators that you cannot get with Annotations (e.g.: Enterprise Library).

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks , i have seen that,, but still i dont know how to display error icon corresponding to controls... have you idea then please share it,, or if you have any code can you share it?

Comment: There's a component for this: ErrorProvider. It displays an icon next to the controls and a message if wanted. You can start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/a0d996e0.aspx

Comment: You will have to invoke your validator on some click event and get back the validation results in order to set ErrorProvider programmatically